# Interactively loading another page to DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm loading another page in to one of my DIVs with

```
 $(divName).load("mypage")
```

Is there a "funner" way to do it ? Have the DIV expand/slide down as the page is appearing ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more serious and specific :) 
I'm just looking to add some interactivity.

It would be great if by pressing a button that makes the DIV below bigger and loads another View into it make the div slide down/expand as well.
Should I execute two commands separately:
1) Expand the DIV down for x-amount of pixels
2) Load the view into it

or is there a better to do it with one command ?

Comment: you could open the page in iframe also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use underscore.js to to a _.defer in the page load event and then inside your _.defer you could do the operations simultaneously:

```
$(divName).load("mypage",function(){
    _.defer(function(){
        $(divName).fadeIn();
        $(divName).slideDown();
    });
});
```

Sounds fun to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(divName).hide().load("mypage",
function(){
    $(divName).slideDown();}
);
```